# Cannot connect constraints to a barrier in the layout editor

Tags: android

I was trying to do [this tutorial on constraint layout.](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/#0)

I've followed it to a tee, and everything was going fine until I reached the [chapter about barriers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/#10)

In step 6, they tell you to delete the constraint that joins an EditText and a TextView, and then create a constraint from that EditText to the barrier.

The thing is, unlike the animated image in step 6.2 of the tutorial, I hover and hover with my arrow around the barrier, but the constraint is not created; the barrier seems impossible to "grab", nothing happens.

I've been trying to solve this problem for a whole day now and I'm completely perplexed. Things that I've tried:

1. Invalidate caches/restart, clean, rebuild project.
2. Checking that everything in build.gradle(module: app) is in the
   latest version.
3. Reloading a fresh version of the project files (in case I downloaded
   a corrupted version or some wrong manipulation of mine had broken something).
4. Looking (both inside Android Studio and online) for some settings
   that should be changed regarding the layout editor.
5. Restoring AS' "factory" configuration.
6. Completely Uninstalling and reinstalling AS.

The AS version I use is 3.5.3.

Has anybody an idea of what could be the cause of this strange problem? Like I say, I wasn't doing anything "outrageous", just following a paint-by-numbers tutorial... Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: The exact same thing happened to me. I'm on Android Studio 3.6. Weirdly, if I add it manually into the XML, the constraint appears in the Design view, but as you described, if I try it directly in the design tab, it simply would not snap to the barrier.

Comment: Yes, that's what I finally found out too, you can get the constraints by writing them in the code. I also tried installing Android Studio 3.6 and the bug was just the same. Well, at least you can get by by writing the stuff into the XML...